# Failing to paramaterize a MySQL Statement in Java in one small way

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-mvc

I'm putting the function parameter into a constructor inside the function (with the aim of that parameter going into a MySQL Statement) `new MapSqlParameterSource("table_name", tableName)`, but it won't receive it.

However, when I hardcode a tableName into the second parameter, it works, and my user interface sees every row with that table name. How can I make it receive the parameter?

The front end is a JSP page and I am using Spring MVC. This below is in the controller class. And the proper tableName is being sent to the function, but I'm not able to get it into the constructor.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{tableName}", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String showEditProductPage(@PathVariable(name = "tableName") String tableName, Model model) {
        
final String FETCH_SQL = "select * from reservations where table_name = :table_name";
     
//this is the part I refer to in my sentence above where if I hard code, it works.
    SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("table_name", tableName);

            List <Guests> guest = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(FETCH_SQL, namedParameters, new RowMapper<Guests>() 
            {public Guests mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException{
                Guests guest = new Guests();
                guest.setId(rs.getLong(1));
                guest.setName(rs.getString(2));
                guest.setTime(rs.getString(3));
                guest.setDate(rs.getString(4));
                guest.setTableName(rs.getString(5));
                return guest;
            }
            });
            model.addAttribute("guests", guest );
    
    return "/edit_guest";

}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying that if you change the code above to `new MapSqlParameterSource("table_name", "table10")` it works? Have you checked that your `tableName` variable is getting set correctly?

Comment: @tgdavies Yes. When I directly type the actual table name, it works. When i paramaterize it and feed the table name through a parameter, it does not work. I have not tried to debug or log what comes out; I will do that. But I'm assuming the correct value is passed because in the URL on the browser interface, it ends up having the correct table name in the URL.

Comment: *"I have not tried to debug or log ..."* That is something you definitely should have done before asking here. --- Question down-voted for **lack of research**, aka debugging your own code.

Comment: Sure, I'll remove the down-vote once you *show* some research in the question text, e.g. logging the value of `tableName`, and show how `new MapSqlParameterSource("table_name", tableName)` fails when `tableName = "foo"`, while `new MapSqlParameterSource("table_name", "foo")` works, like you claim it does when hardcoding the value. Given that it would end up executing the exact same SQL, I find your claim hard to believe.

Comment: You say *"when I hardcode a tableName into the **second** parameter"*, but there is only one parameter, so what "second" parameter are you talking about?

Comment: @Andreas thank you again for the constructive part of your feedback. I will attempt to log the value in the morning. As far as the second parameter, I mean the second parameter of the constructor.